database record delete User.find_by_id().address.destroy
I am trying to delete the address result from here.
I can add new address by doing this but I can't delete it
 $User.find_by_id(19).update(address: "canada")

I tried this but it is not working
 $User.find_by_id(19).destroy(address: "canada")

The output of
$User.find_by_id(19).destroy(address: "canada")
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 19]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
       10: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        9: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        8: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        7: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        6: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        3: from (irb):2
        2: from (irb):2:in `rescue in irb_binding'
        1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:280:in `destroy'
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))


@dbugger User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 19]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
10: from bin/rails:4:in <main>'         9: from bin/rails:4:in require'

@dbugger I just add it

Destroy doesn’t take any arguments. It will destroy the user found by the id

User.find(19).update(address: nil)

The question doesn't make sense. update(address: "canada") updates a column on the database row. destroy removes the entire row from the database. If you're trying null out the value you would use update(address: nil). See https://xyproblem.info/

I think you are trying to update the address field value from Canada to nil. If that's the case, what you are looking for is update, not destroy:
User.find(19).update(address: nil)


You can change your filter into below:
User.find_by(id: 19, address: "canada").destroy


is this going to destroy the user or the address? because i want to delete just the address

It will remove the user row.

What do you mean to delete address? Is the address field in the users table?

try to nullify address if it is property of User
User.find(19).update!(address: nil)

or try to delete address if it association of User
User.find(19).address.destroy!

